# Woocommerce wc_get_products() $args - how to display posts that have “all” of tags specified?

Tags: woocommerce

I need wc_get_products() to select products by tags, but only select products that have all of the tags specified.

Example:

***Product A*** has product tags **TagX** and **TagY**.

***Product B*** has product tags **TagX**.

If I set:

```
$args = array(
        'tag' => array('TagX', 'TagY')
);
```

wc_get_products() returns **Product A** and **Product B**, but I want it to return only ***Product A*** in this case.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following - I have not tested it but I believe you should get a gist of what I am trying to convey,

```
$args = array(
    'tag'      => array('TagX', 'TagY'),
    'return'   => 'objects'
);
$list_of_woocommerce_products = wc_get_products($args);
$required_array_of_objects = array();
$tag = get_term_by('slug', 'TagX');
$tag_id_X =  $tag->term_id;
$tag = get_term_by('slug', 'TagY');
$tag_id_Y =  $tag->term_id;
foreach($list_of_woocommerce_products as $single_woocommerce_product){
  if( in_array($tag_id_X, $single_woocommerce_product->get_tag_ids()) && in_array($tag_id_X, $single_woocommerce_product->get_tag_ids()) ){
        array_push($required_array_of_objects,$single_woocommerce_product);
     }
    }
//Required array of Woocommerce products having tags X and Y
print_r($required_array_of_objects);
```

Please study and analyze the above ***untested-code***. Make suitable modifications after getting the basic idea and intimate me the outcome.

Comment: Didn't tested this yet, but I got your idea. Thanks!

Comment: That is great! I will be very grateful if you mark my answer as 'Correct'. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like it works, just get_term_by() should include 3rd parameter, taxonomy name, in this case 'product_tag'.